# Webscraping - Adding a If Statement if a "Nontype" object has no attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, non-type

Thanks for reading!  For my project what I am doing is scrolling through company annual reports to pull names of board members and positions.  Because different companies have different formats I would like to try a method to scrape information, and if that process results in a "Nontype" error (because one method does not find attributes or a keyword), to move to a different method and try that method.  I just need a way to say if there is a nontype error, try the next method.  Below is one method that results in an error.

```
tables_ticker = annual_report_page_soup.find(text="Age").find_parent("table")
resticker = []
for row in tables_ticker.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    #print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
    if row:
        resticker.append([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
        non_empty_ticker = [sublist for sublist in resticker if any(sublist)]
        df_ticker = pd.DataFrame.from_records(non_empty_ticker)
        df_ticker[df_ticker == ''] = np.nan
        df_ticker=df_ticker.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

print(df_ticker)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Edgar/WMT Working.py", line 84, in 
    tables_ticker = annual_report_page_soup.find(text="Age").find_parent("table")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example you can apply to your code:

```
for item in ["Hello", "World", None, "Foo", None, "Bar"]:
    print(item.upper())
```

Output:

```
HELLO
WORLD
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'
>>>
```

As you can see, once the for-loop reaches the third item in the list (which is not a string, it's a `NoneType` object), an exception is raised because `NoneType` objects don't have an `upper` method. This worked for the first two iterations because strings do have an `upper` method.

Solution - use a try-except block:

```
for item in ["Hello", "World", None, "Foo", None, "Bar"]:
    try:
        print(item.upper())
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Output:

```
HELLO
WORLD
FOO
BAR
>>>
```

We encapsulated the line of code which can throw a potential `AttributeError` with a try-except block. If the line of code raises such an exception, we use the `continue` keyword to skip this iteration of the loop and move on to the next item in the list.

In the same way, you can encapsulate this line:

`tables_ticker = annual_report_page_soup.find(text="Age").find_parent("table")`

With a try-except block. Instead of using `continue` inside a loop, however, you can switch scraping formats.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  For some reason I spent a couple days trying to find something that would work and could not.  I really appreciate the fast response and clarity from you.  Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed!